# When upgrading the smart contract to v0.7.6 of masterchef v2 getting this error TypeError: The "using for" directive is not allowed inside interfaces

Tags: solidity, sushiswap

```
interface IRewarder {
using BoringERC20 for IERC20;
function onSushiReward(uint256 pid, address user, address recipient, uint256 sushiAmount, uint256 newLpAmount) external;
function pendingTokens(uint256 pid, address user, uint256 sushiAmount) external view returns (IERC20[] memory, uint256[] memory);
```

}

Getting error: contracts/Masterchiefv2.sol:364:5: TypeError: The "using for" directive is not allowed inside interfaces.
using BoringERC20 for IERC20;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because interfaces can't use libraries like that (it was allowed but completely useless before, now it's forbidden) just delete this line.